# Who is responsible for providing `set -o pipefail`

Tags: bash, shell-script, portability, shellcheck

I want strict mode in my scripts. I would also appreciate portability.

[set -o pipefail](https://www.translucentcomputing.com/2020/11/unofficial-bash-strict-mode-pipefail/) seems compulsory. Yet `shellcheck`(a static linter) is unhappy that "In POSIX sh, set option pipefail is undefined".

Is it correct? If so, is this a `bash` solely feature or is it rather prolific?

Comment: What do you mean by *compulsory*? `set -o pipefail` is not defined in the current POSIX.1-2017: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `pipefail` shell option is specific to a number of shells that `shellcheck` claims to support<sup>1</sup>.  You can use this shell option and be portable, if by "portability" you assume that any target system has a shell that supports it (and any other constructs that you may be using).  This is the same type of "portability" that you get with any other specific scripting language.

The `shellcheck` linter will complain if it finds `set -o pipefail` in a shell script that is a `sh` script, since it's currently not supported by POSIX `sh`.

To ensure that your script is a script interpreted by the `bash` shell (or any specific shell that you are coding for), the script should have a `#!`-line pointing to the correct shell interpreter, e.g.,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
```

or possibly

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

or something similar.

With a proper `#!`-line that additionally indicates that the script will be interpreted by a particular shell that is not `sh`, the `shellcheck` linter will not complain about you setting the `pipefail` shell option in your script.

If you don't use a `#!`-line in your scripts, then you should consider doing so (or always run your scripts with an explicit interpreter on the command line).  Meanwhile, the `shellcheck` command line tool can be told to switch to mode using its `-s` (or `--shell=`) option:

```bsh
shellcheck --shell=bash myscript
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I suspect that `shellcheck` has a "POSIX `sh` mode" and an "other mode" to support `bash`, `dash`, and `ksh` (`shellcheck` does not claim to support `zsh`).  The `pipefail` shell option is documented to work with `bash`, and `ksh`.  The `zsh` shell has a `PIPE_FAIL` shell option that can be set in the same way.  The `dash` shell does not support the option, but if the `#!`-line mentions `dash`, `shellcheck` won't complain about `pipefail`.</sub>

Comment: It does not complain if using `ksh` or `dash` only `sh`. For `sh` it is on from v0.7. (If I [read this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/990) correctly) On my system `set -o pipefail` has effect on `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh` albeit strange error code in `ksh` (93u+) - fails (as expected) with `sh`, `dash`, `tcsh` ...

Comment: @ibuprofen I suspect that `shellcheck` has a "POSIX `sh` mode" and an "other mode".  The `pipefail` shell option is documented to work with `bash`, and `ksh`.  The `zsh` shell has a `PIPE_FAIL` shell option that can be set in the same way.  Dash does not support the option.

Comment: In `zsh`, case and underscores are ignored in option names, so `set -o pipefail` works as well. In `yash`, that's case, underscores or hyphens, so `set -o PIPE_FAIL`, `set -o PIPE-FAIL` or `set -o --pipefail` (but also `set --pipe-fail`) would also work. In `bash`, case is significant and underscore/hyphens are not ignored. bash also has 2 sets of options, one set with `set -o`, the other with `shopt -s`. Some of the ones set with `set -o` can also be passed as `bash --option`, but not `pipefail`.

Comment: Such a simple solution. Such a comprehensive answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

The `pipefail` option comes from ksh93 and is also present in a few other shells.  It was added:

- [to ksh93g](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/blob/e939860a86e1c9f1e7eb0a971d4bc2c5336efc9d/src/cmd/ksh93/RELEASE#L2735) released in 1998
- [to bash](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CWRU/CWRU.chlog?h=bash-3.0-beta#n8338) 3.0 released in 2004
- [to busybox ash in 2009](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=359da5e3be3dfb15913c4e76d0b4a27b6400adc5)
- [to busybox hush in 2010](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=6696eac274b5dcf5932b211fe9ee748d8268a39c)
- [to mksh](https://github.com/MirBSD/mksh/commit/ff42a866e9e0a51ac01cb29ef8a3b6f6cefbb3d3) r46 released in 2013
- [to zsh](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2013/msg00499.html) 5.0.3 released in 2013
- [to yash 2.42](https://osdn.net/projects/yash/scm/svn/blobs/3661/yash/trunk/NEWS) released in 2016
- [to NetBSD sh in 2017](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/commit/14821fe11c4bebf90c08bcb0605801c7aafc76d7)
- [to FreeBSD sh in 2019](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/commit/484160a9cf236a5892c1ab8344de287d7a1472c1)
- [to OpenBSD sh in 2020](https://github.com/openbsd/src/commit/cbb0b321fa62f17a1e02f67ceb4d6f5f7bdc606b)

A [request to add it to the POSIX standard](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=789) was submitted in 2013 and a resolution accepted in 2019. So it will be in the next major revision of the standard due soon.

It will still probably take some more time for remaining implementations (mostly dash, bosh and ksh88-based shells) to add support for it. After which the "EOL" clock will start ticking and 10 years later you'll be able to assume all sh implementations on currently supported systems will support it.

Comment: It is included in the current POSIX draft P1003.1™-202x/D2.1 (August 2021, at page 2383): *pipefail Derive the exit status of a pipeline from the exit statuses of all of the commands in the pipeline, not just the last (rightmost) command, as described in Section 2.9.2.*

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to happen when script runs on shell that doesn't support `pipefail`?

Turns out order matters on *some* shells but is not the whole story.  bash cares about order even within single `set` command — it continues on `set -o NoSuchOption -e` vs. exits on `set -e -o NoSuchOption`.

- If you want to exit if pipefail is not supported, `set -e; set -o pipefail` looks enough.  (the shells I tried print an error message in such case)

But it gets worse: `bash --posix` (== /bin/sh on many systems) and `dash` exit immediately on `set -o NoSuchOption` even without `set -e` anywhere!
bash can be appeased by `set -o NoSuchOption || true` (not sure why that works) but not dash, it really crashes on the spot.

- If you want to continue running on all shells, even ones that don't support `pipefail`, it looks like you must first probe whether it's supported.  This is best I came up with for `bash`, `bash --posix` and `dash`, no idea if it's portable yet more other shells:

```
set -e
trap '
  s=$? p=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
  echo "$0: Error ${p[*]} on line $LINENO: $BASH_COMMAND" 1>&2
  exit $s
' ERR 2>/dev/null || true

set -o | grep -q pipefail && set -o pipefail
echo cont1

true | sh -c 'exit 2' | false | true
echo cont2

true | sh -c 'exit 3'
echo cont3
```

Here `bash` (whether posix mode or not) stops on the mid-pipeline errors:

```
cont1
t.sh: Error 0 2 1 0 on line 13: true
```

while `dash` doesn't support pipefail, only aborted where right-most command exited non-0:

```
cont1
cont2
```

dash also doesn't support ERR traps (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58297505/239657 tries to approximate it but not well enough imho)

- ❓ but is this a good idea?  You risk writing code that assumes `pipefail` is in effect but it might not be; and you can't explicitly check `$PIPESTATUS` array, e.g. dash doesn't have it either.

  So this was an interesting exercise, but I'd recommend to exit where pipefail is unsupported.  And IMHO once you care about such things you want to require `bash` specifically — it gives you other goodies too like `ERR`, printing stack traces with `$BASH_SOURCE`, `$BASH_LINENO`, `$FUNCNAME` arrays etc...